# Redis : incr a value from a hget key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Firstly I'm new to Redis so please bear with me, as I'm sure this is a simple solution.

I'm trying to **incr** a value from within my hash. This is how I'm setting my key `'hset user:likes 2 10'` so the first part is my key followed by another key, which is the users id number and then the value (10). What I need to do is **incr** the value of 10 to 11 but I'm not sure how to do this. I know I can use `'hget user:likes:total:count 2'` to return the value but how do I then use the **incr** command as well as the **hget** command at the same time?

I'm using Ruby on Rails to implement this by the way using the redis gem.

Comment: This page is your best friend: http://redis.io/commands

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [HINCRBY](http://redis.io/commands/hincrby):

```
$redis.hincrby("user:likes", 2, 1)
```

I'm a little unclear on your key structure as described above. But basically, you pass in the name of the hash ("user:likes"), the hash key (in this case, I'm assuming a user id of 2), and the value by which you want to increment (in this case, 1).